# sqlalchemy: Order query after UNION

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two different tables but both tables have a date object. I would like to query both tables at the same time to get a mixed list of objects ordered by date.
I need to do this in one step, so that I can use the paginate command. I cannot just query two lists and combine them afterwards.

UPDATE: I tried

```
dummy = query1.union(query2).order_by('date').all()
```

but that results in

```
ArgumentError: All selectables passed to CompoundSelect must have identical numbers of columns; select #1 has 8 columns, select #2 has 24
```

thanks
carl

Comment: [`UNION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html)

Comment: how can I include the order_by(date) condition? Note that the date colume is called date in one table and vote_datetime in the other...

Comment: [You can alias columns.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score -1):

This is not a perfect solution because it requires digging a bit into SQLAlchemy internals. But it seems to work. Perhaps someone can help finish it up and make it more robust.

```
# You need to have Model.date in both query1 and query2. 
# No promises if your models are complex or have multiple columns called dates or something!
from sqlalchemy import text
base_query = query1.union(query2)
ordered_query = base_query.order_by(text(f"{next(i for i in base_query.column_descriptions if i['name']=='date')['expr'].name} desc"))
```